# Lim sup as a random variable in a bounded interval?

Tags: probability

Let (Ω, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P}$) be a probability space and, for each t ∈ [0, 1], let $X_t$ be a random variable on (Ω, F, P). For $\omega \in \Omega$

Y($\omega$): = sup $X_t(\omega$) with $t \in [0,1]$

Is Y a random variable on (Ω, $\mathcal{F}$, $\mathbb{P}$)?

I know it is a r.v. when it is unbounded but why in this situation too?

Answer (score 0):

You want to check $Y$ is a measurable function, right?

There's some theorem saying if a class of functions $f_t(x)$ are measurable, then so does $\sup_t f_t(x)$.
So if you consider $w$ as $x$ here, this theorem applies.